# Git setup for 70 users in multiple location

Tags: git

I'm tasked to brinup git for 70 users located in multiple location. What could be the best approach ? Where can i start from ?

Planned following

bare repository
ssh setup for RW access
http setup for RO access

Let me know how to proceed ?

BRs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fear this question is not quite specific enough to get decent answers. You might want to take some time to do more research and come back with more targeted questions.

Comment: I think it's fairly well specified and answerable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you already have a planned approach, since you have no specific problem I'd recommend you brush up on the [git tutorials](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.2.6/tutorial.html) to make sure you are familiar with the software before deploying it to others.

Set up a [central repository](http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux) on a server, instruct the other users to download Git and pull from the central repository using:

```
git clone http://yourserver.yourdomain.com/sharedproject.git
```

How you manage the VCS after this really depends on your requirements.

One approach is to have production builds made exclusively on one central server - have one privileged person with push (SSH) access to the server, and everyone elses work is pushed or pulled to that privileged person before a build.

There are, however, many other ways to manage your workflow with Git, and no single method suits everyone. You need to establish this workflow before attempting to fit a DVCS into it.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible for you to give more info about setting ssh access

Comment: A standard OpenSSH server would do the trick, it will use your system login credentials - there are plenty of tutorials on the Web on how to do this. There are some good tips here: http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of git is that it really doesn't matter.  Each developer can work on their own machine and push/pull from/to each other.  It would certainly simplify things if a policy decision is made so that one repository is designated the "official" code base, perhaps a repo maintained by the project lead.  It is common to store that repo on a machine that all developers can access and pull from, while only a few developers have access to push to it.

Comment: Can i have multiple rep in one server, say each rep for modules and modules owner can push it to official one.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple repositories on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach is fine but if you want a semi github like experience, you can consider using [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/).